# How to show a div that contain a The jQuery UI Selectable on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to find a mouse position that was clicked on and  a div that contains  a  show up,this div should contain a Selectable
I know how to find a mouse position and show a div,but I got an error when I tried to fill a div with selectable.
Can you show me a sample how to write this script?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectNewsType" ).click(function(e) {
                  $("<ol/>",{
            "id" : "selectable",
            "style":"border:1px solid;width:200px;position:absolute;left:" + (e.pageX - 200) + "px;top:" + e.pageY + "px;"

        }).appendTo("body")
        .append( $(function(){
            $.each(a.rows,function(k,v){
                $("<li>",{      
                    id:k,
                    text:a.rows[k].cell[0],
                    className:"ui-widget-content"

                }).appendTo("#selectable");
            })           
        }))
        .show();

    });
});
```

Comment: What was the error you received? What code was it that produced this error? Please give more information

Comment: @Ben Stephenson:           
I got this error:Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy" code: "3

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple example using jQuery selectable example - [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/kwicher/GTwuC/15/). First the div containing selectable is hidden, upon clicking anyway it is showed. I did not bothered with getting mouse position but otherwise it works.

Is this what you wanted?

K